# Ownership of Tags

Tags: feature-request

Since some of the tags are specific to some specific products, can a tag be "claimed" by the development team of the product (authorization process takes place of course), so that the development team will be notified by email of new / unanswered questions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without needing to "own" the tag. Just set up a subscription on Stack Exchange and direct the emails to some global team email, and everyone will be notified of recent activity, new questions, etc.

Check out [Stack Exchange Filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters)

Just set up a filter for Stack Overflow and include any tags that your development team should be checking. Then you can subscribe and receive emails every 15 minutes, 3 hours, or daily.